# Passing ... parameters in C

Tags: c

I want to create this function, but ... parameter lists can't be passed around this way. What is the proper way to go about this?

And yes, I know some compilers provide an 'asprintf'. My question is not what function I should be using, but rather how to get parameter passing like this to work.

```
// Allocates a formmated string
char *msprintf(const char *format, ...)
{
    int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, ...);

    char *buf = (char*)malloc(size);
    snprintf(buf, size, format, ...);

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: In my limited experience, va_args is the only way I think.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html

Comment: Use [`vsnprintf(3)`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_vsnprintf.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You would use [`vsnprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) inside the call.

```
char *msprintf(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    int size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, args);
    char *buf = malloc(size);
    vsnprintf(buf, size, format, args);

    va_end(args);
    return buf;
}
```